# HttpServlet contracts for doGet and doPost

Tags: java, http, servlets

Is there any contract of request processing for doPost and doGet methods(except that doGet is idempotent and doPost is not) for the servlet class which extends `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`. Is it ok to send nothing in response or it's mandatory to do forward or write something in response?

Comment: Based on the Javadoc I saw nothing mentioned about a required response.  Why do you ask?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, yeah, I've checked javadoc also, if we do nothing with response it just returns http status 200. I just want to implement simple reporting servlet and store request to log file, no requirements about response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not mandatory to write to response, however you might consider to send an [HTTP Status 204 No Content](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5) in that case.